# Ionic cordova build android ERROR

Tags: android, ionic, cordova, ionic3, ionic-framework

Quiero hacer un build de mi app Ionic en mi dispositivo Android, y en consola sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Android Studio, tengo instalados los siguientes SDK:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo instalado los build-tools de Android, de hecho tengo instalado, según lo que dice Android Studio: "Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc2", y también tengo instalado el "Android SDK Platform-Tools".

Mis variables de entorno, para mi usuario son:

```
-ANDROID_HOME: C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
-ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
-CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
-GRADLE_USER_HOME: C:\Users\Fabio\.gradle
-JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241
```

En la variable PATH incluí todas estas variables:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo `package.json`de mi proyecto tengo instalados los siguientes paquetes, y que tienen que ver con toda esta posibilidad de utilizar los dispositivos Android para ejecutar la aplicación, y manejar cosas como el login con Facebook, con Google+, usar Google Maps, etc.:

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/facebook": "^5.22.0",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^4.21.0",
"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.22.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.4.0",
    "ionic": "^3.20.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
```

Probé las siguientes soluciones que busqué en Internet:

- Borrar la carpeta `node_modules` y hacer `npm install`.
- Corregir las variables de entorno correspondientes y ejecutar el
  comando `ionic cordova build android`.
- Actualizar el paquete `ionic-native` a la última versión (o a una versión específica, como
  está descripto en la lista de dependencias    de arriba.
- Ejecutar el comando `ionic cordova platform rm android`, y luego `ionic cordova platform add android`

Ejecuté el comando `ionic requirements -l`, y obtuve el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a lo de arriba, probé las soluciones mencionadas arriba, incluso borrar Android Studio, e instalar de nuevo todo (el build-tools y el platform-tools, y los SDK), y no hubo caso.
No sé qué es lo que me falta instalar o qué es que tengo mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error de No installed build tools found se debe al a version "Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc2"

Esa versión no es estable, en Android Studio ve hacia Tools, SDK Manager y selecciona la pestaña de SDK TOOLS, ahi desmarca la casilla "Hide obsolte Packages" e istala el Android SDK Tools (obsolete).

Luego de ahí selecciona la casilla que dice Package details y despliega el SDK Build-tools 30-rc2 elimina esa versión e instala cualquiera que no sea rc.

Por ese lado estarías bien.